# Are there recursive types in the theory of simple types? If not, how do I prove it?

Tags: recursion, lambda-calculus, type-theory

In the book I am reading, the set of simple types $\mathbb{T}$ is defined by:

1. If $\alpha \in \mathbb{V}$, then $\alpha \in \mathbb{T}$
2. If $\sigma, \tau \in \mathbb{T}$ then $(\sigma \to \tau) \in \mathbb{T}$

Later one of the exercises asked to "investigate whether or not $xyx$ could be typed with a simple type".

My derivation for $xyx$ reasoned that, in order for this to be well typed $x$ must have type $\delta \to (\sigma \to \tau)$ and it must also have type $\sigma$. Clearly this is a contradiction...

or is it??

If $xyx$ was well typed, this would mean that $x$ would have a type $\sigma$ such that $\sigma = \delta \to (\sigma \to \tau)$ due to the uniqueness of types.

This doesn't seem to be okay, but I tried to think of a way to prove that there were no recursive types.

However, as far as I know, there is nothing stopping $\sigma$ from being in the set $\mathbb{V}$, in which case, $\sigma$ is a perfectly valid type.

Is there some flaw in my reasoning, or is there something that doesn't allow simple types to be recursive?

Comment: To be precise $\mathbb T$ was probably stated as being the *smallest* set satisfying 1 and 2, and, as Luca Bressan states, usually we assume that $\sigma\to\tau\notin\mathbb V$ for any $\sigma$ and $\tau$ at all. This assumption can be dropped if you explicitly form a disjoint union, e.g. do something like $\alpha\in\mathbb V$ implies $(0,\alpha)\in\mathbb T$ and $(1,\sigma\to\tau)$ for the other case. If you spell out what "smallest" means set-theoretically, you'll see that it is more or less an induction rule which enables defining functions by recursion as Luca Bressan does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can inductively define a function $n \colon \mathbb T \to \mathbb N$ counting the number of arrows of a simple type as follows:

1. If $\alpha \in \mathbb V$, then $n(\alpha) = 0$.
2. If $\sigma, \tau \in \mathbb T$, then $n(\sigma \to \tau) = n(\sigma) + n(\tau) + 1$.

The function $n$ is well-defined, because each type can either be an element of $\mathbb V$ or have the form $\sigma \to \tau$ for some types $\sigma, \tau$, but *it can't be both*: this is implicitly assumed by the fact that $\mathbb T$ is inductively defined by the rules 1 and 2 above.

You have already shown that in order for $x y x$ to be well-typed, there would have to be a type $\sigma$ such that $\sigma = \delta \to (\sigma \to \tau)$ for some types $\delta, \tau$. But this implies that

$$n(\sigma) = n(\delta \to (\sigma \to \tau)) = n(\delta) + n(\sigma) + n(\tau) + 2 > n(\sigma)$$

which is a contradiction, therefore there can be no such $\sigma$. Notice in particular that the contradiction holds even if we assume that $\sigma \in \mathbb V$.

Comment: I was writing an analogous answer but then I realized that actually OP's question can be reformulated as follows: "why this function $n$ is well-defined?". If you have a type $\alpha = \alpha \to \alpha$, the function $n$ is not well-defined. I mean, OP's question is deeper than it seems, at least to me.

Comment: The function $n$ is well-defined because its definition follows the inductive rules that define $\mathbb T$. In order for there to be a type $\alpha$ such that $\alpha = \alpha \to \alpha$, we would have to consider a quotient of $\mathbb T$.

Comment: Of course, there can be a type $\alpha$ that is isomorphic to $\alpha \to \alpha$ according to some definition of isomorphism between types (e.g., the unit type).

Comment: I see your point (of course, I don't care about isomorphisms here) but suppose that in $\mathbb{V}$ (intended as a set of variables) there is an element that is syntactically written as $\alpha \to \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{V}$. In other words, why do the inductive rules that define $\mathbb{T}$ imply that there are not identities between simple types, except for the trivial one $\tau = \tau$ for any $\tau \in \mathbb{T}$?

Comment: This is because in any inductive definition the constructors are assumed to be disjoint and injective. For example, when we define the type $\mathsf {Nat}$ of natural numbers by the rules:
$$\frac {} {\mathsf 0 \in \mathsf {Nat}} \qquad \frac {n \in \mathsf {Nat}} {\mathsf{succ}(n) \in \mathsf {Nat}}$$
we are implicitly saying that $0 \neq \mathsf{succ}(n)$ for any $n$ and that $\mathsf{succ}(m) \neq \mathsf{succ}(n)$ whenever $m \neq n$.

Comment: I guess this is the point.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thank you for your remarks, I have edited my answer to make this point clearer.